# Serverless.Framework Deployment Error - Function not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

In my sls infrastructure I have an authorizer function that I created and connected to most of my other functions.
when I deployed it sequentially (first the auth function, then the connection to the other functions) all worked as expected. However, when I want to deploy everything to a new environment, I get the error that my auth function is not found, and I think its because it is not yet created when Cloudformation is trying to reference it.

My question is this:
**Can I specify dependency between resources? so that I will deploy a resource only after its dependency is deployed.**

If not, how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Yes. You can use DependsOn attribute of CloudFormation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shimo , but I meant a "dependsOn" key in serverless.yml. I don't have intention in modifying the CloudFormation json.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the function and a custom authorizer function for it in the same Serverless Framework service (as is evident also from the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers)).

If you run into problems with a fresh deploy that could indicate a bug in Serverless Framework - timing problems between functions in CloudFormation stacks have been common in it. You can always try upgrading your `sls`.

In bigger projects it's common to isolate authorizer functions to their own stack (referenced from several other stacks) which sidesteps this internal dependency issue - in that case you naturally deploy the authorizer stack first.